# Best way to store articles from the internet for future search

Tags: database, postgresql

Every day I visit the site and save all of your text content to some database.

One of the sites I'm going to save is 505 kb, is there any way I can save this in the database by reducing size without losing data?

The saved information has to be available to search for keywords, so I can find content saved on previous dates.

Using a nosql bank would be a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing may be well-fit by [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch), which can be used as a distributed text-searching engine.

You also asked about "reducing size without losing data?"  This is [lossless coompression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/archiving.html), and it's very friendly to memory, but may inhibit your ability to actually do the searching, since that might require decompressing each string first, itself an O(N) operation that effectively defeats the point.

You also mentioned a NoSQL store versus a relational database.  It's the right thinking, but still might not be an exact match.  Related to a NoSQL store is [Redis](https://redis.io/), an in-memory key-value store.  However, Redis is commonly used for *lookups*, i.e. "I give you a URL; you give me back the cached page HTML associated with that URL."  That doesn't exactly describe your case and its particularities, which might not fit well into the Redis model.  So again, Elasticsearch is probably a good place to start.